# How to disable displaying results of stored procedure in the query of SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure `sp_query1` which will return results of a specific query.

I only want to get the rowcount returned from this stored procedure. Currently I can do it using following statement:

```
exec sp_query1 @para=1
select @@rowcount as cnt
```

It will display the result of the stored procedure first, then the rowcount:

```
column1, column2, column3, ....
....     ....     ....
....     ....     ....
....     ....     ....
....     ....     ....

cnt
....
```

But this becomes annoying if I want to run multiple queries:

```
exec sp_query1 @para=1
select @@rowcount as cnt1
exec sp_query1 @para=2
select @@rowcount as cnt2
exec sp_query1 @para=3
select @@rowcount as cnt3
```

because I only want to get the rowcount of each query. Is it possible to mute the result of the stored procedure? (I have no permission to rewrite this stored procedure)

Thanks.

Comment: Well you could use a cursor to call it with a list of parameters and store the rowcount of each execution into a temp

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!